# Edge - navigating on Angular iframe sets history.state to null

Tags: angular, iframe, microsoft-edge, angular-router

We have an Angular 7 app that sits inside an iframe on all of our clients websites. All the navigation inside the app is done through this helper class:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from "@angular/router";

@Injectable()
export class NavigationService {

constructor(private router: Router)
{}

    private navigate(path, queryParams = {}){
        this.router.navigate([path], {
            queryParams: queryParams,
            skipLocationChange: true
        }));
    }
}
```

One of our clients has some JS code (on their main site, not our iframe) that tries to access `history.state.persistent` *again, on the main window). On Chrome and Firefox everything works fine, but on Microsoft Edge `history.state` is null.

We're positive that something in our iframe is causing it, as removing the iframe fixes the issue. We also `console.log`ged the history object at set intervals, and we see that at some point during our app initialization the `state` field becomes null.

Looking through the Angular Router docs I couldn't find anything related, any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Which exact version of MS Edge you are using for making this test? As you said something in your iframe causing this issue but we don't have any information about your iframe. so even if we try to reproduce the issue than it will not generate that error. If possible than try to create any sample code which we can directly run in edge to test the issue. Also you can try to refer this link may give helpful information. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/28108

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly is causing this bug but I think you might want to test some of the ExtraOptions settings on the RouterModule.forRoot().

```
interface ExtraOptions {
    useHash?: boolean;
    initialNavigation?: InitialNavigation;

}
```

https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm not sure why, but setting the `initialNavigation` to 'disabled' did the trick. All I had to do then was to simply navigate to the default route of the app manually. Still have no idea why the initialNavigation would cause such a problem...

Comment: amazing, so happy I could help